# Library to generate dynamic Google Maps markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-visualization

Google has [recently deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) its Image Charts API and we are looking for a replacement to their [Dynamic Icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons) generator, which we used to generate Google Maps markers.  For example something like:

[image]

generated by this URL:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|Stack%20Overflow|C6EF8C|000000

Is there any public service, or library which we could deploy in our server to replace this API ?

Answer (score 1):

There exists an open-source project named [Google Maps Utility Library V3](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) that has individual libraries for creating [infoboxes](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) under markers

[image]

and [markers with labels](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel)

[image]

[or styled markers with labels](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#StyledMarker)

[image]

Wonder if these could be useful in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately StyledMarkers in google-maps-utility-library-v3 are just a wrapper over Google Charts API, so they are also "deprecated".  But maybe we could replace our Dynamic Icons by MarkerWithLabel because they don't seem to depend on Google Charts API.  Thanks for your help!